# How to add new pages to nopcommerce?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I'm using nopcommerce open source.

So I want to add a new part. It has different tables and different pages and different logic.

So I don't know how to do it.

I want to add new part for hire items. So it has different tables and have to enter user information. It also different page and go to another new table.And also I have to add another terms and condition page.

If anybody have any idea or do you know any link about how to do it step by step

Comment: That's incredibly vague, can you give more details on what you want your new part to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend writing a plugin. You can learn how to do this in the following post.
https://docs.nopcommerce.com/developer/plugins/index.html

It means you can separate your logic from the core nopCommerce logic and therefore be able to update the nopCommerce solution in the future with no problems.

As long as you set all of your Views to have a build action of Embedded Resource, you shouldn't have any problems adding new pages.

Answer (score 2):

just add new controller if you want to use nopcommerce basic functionality then Inherit it from BaseNopController, then classes in NOP.Core,NOP.Domain and NOP.Service after that register your repository and service in DependencyRegistrar.cs Or you can do this by registering New AREA in nopcommerec.